# Incompatible pointer types initialising although my method returning (id) type

Tags: objective-c

I have method that used to return instance of "Card" class and I changed it to id.
after I changed it, I'm somehow get this warning "Incompatible pointer types initializing 'SetCard *' with an expression of type 'Card *'"

So why does the compiler tell me it expected 'Card *' if I changed it to id? I've tried to clean the project and rebuilt but nothing worked.

```
    -(id) CardAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index
    {
        return (index < [self.cards count]) ? self.cards[index] : nil;
    }
```

Here is where I call the method above

```
 ......
    if ([[self.game CardAtIndex:cardIndex] isMemberOfClass:[PlayingCard class]])
                {
                        PlayingCard *card=[self.game CardAtIndex:cardIndex];
                        .............
                        .............
    }
```

Comment: Did you change it in the header file, too? Also, are you sure of the line of code with the error? The message says "SetCard *" but I don't see that on your line of code.

Comment: Also, why did you do this?  the method 'cardAtIndex' (You should use lower case for methods, upper case first letter for classes) should return a PlayingCard (or possibly a PlayingCard sub-class).  As per @JesseRusak - where is the call to setCard - this is where you are getting an error

Comment: of course!! i can't believe i forgot it. why the compiler didn't alert me for doing this?! thank you very much @Jesse Rusak